# Problems trying to get data

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application that sends data and represents it in a graph, the problem is that when I print the data it does it the way I want it, but when returning the data it only sends the first one, not the rest.

This is my view.

```
class DeveloperDatailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'dates/dates.html'
    model = Developer

    def activities_porcentage(self):
        projects = Project.objects.filter(developer=self.kwargs['pk'])
        for project in projects:
            tasks = Task.objects.filter(project=project).filter(state=True)
            for task in tasks:
                activities = Activities.objects.filter(task=task).count()
                complete = Activities.objects.filter(task=task).filter(process=False).count()
                data = int((complete * 100) / activities)

                return data

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.filter(
            developer=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['quantity'] = Project.objects.filter(
            developer=self.kwargs['pk']).count()
        context['activities'] = self.activities_porcentage()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it seems like you need to add the data you are processing to a list and then return the list at the end of your for loop e.g

```py
def activities_porcentage(self):
    projects = Project.objects.filter(developer=self.kwargs['pk'])
    data = []
    for project in projects:
        tasks = Task.objects.filter(project=project).filter(state=True)
        for task in tasks:
            activities = Activities.objects.filter(task=task).count()
            complete = Activities.objects.filter(task=task).filter(process=False).count()
            data.append(int((complete * 100) / activities))

    return data
```

At the moment you have a return statement returning `data` after the first iteration.